# Scroll at bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, css

I am making a chat app in angular js and I have added the scroll bar to the chat area.
Here is the code:

```
<div class="chat active-chat" id="scrollme" >
   <div class="scroll">
      <div ng-repeat="c in activeConversations track by c.time| orderBy:'time':false" >
         <div class="bubble" ng-class="c.type" >
            {{c.message}} <br/>
            <a style="color: blue;" ng-click="openFile(c.uploadedFile.fileContentType, c.uploadedFile.file)" ng-if="c.uploadedFile.file" target="_blank">{{c.uploadedFile.fileName}}
            </a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class="user_message">{{c.time | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and css for this is:

```
.scroll{
   overflow-y: auto;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}

#scrollme{
   height:         403px;
   width:          498px;
   padding-right:  10px;
   padding-bottom: 76px;
   padding-left:   12px;
}
```

Now I want to keep the scroll at bottom by default and whenever a message arrives it should scroll up.

Thanks in advance

Comment: var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea_id');
textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;

Answer (score 0):

**Keeping it at the bottom:**

You can just set the scrollTop to the height of the element:

Changing the following element: `<div id="innerScroll" class="scroll">`

```
var ele = document.getElementById('scrollme');
var innerEle = document.getElementById('innerScroll') //add this ID to your scroll class element. Or whatever name you want to
var height = innerEle.offsetHeight;
ele.scrollTop = height;
```

See a fiddle for this feature: https://jsfiddle.net/qyj4h73g/1/

**For the chat updating the elements scrollTop value:**

Assuming that the chat object that is constantly being updated is in JSON representation, you can just watch that JSON string value:

```
$scope.$watch('activeConversations', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  var ele = document.getElementById('scrollme');
  var curScrollTop = ele.scrollTop;
  ele.scrollTop = curScrollTop - 16; //Go up 16 pixels, but you can change this as you need
});
```